# Is there a patch preventing hacker from accessing a shell with root privileges on LUKS encrypted system?

Tags: grub2, encryption, luks

I recently came across [this November 2016 article](http://thehackernews.com/2016/11/hacking-linux-system.html).

I tried what they said and pressed the Enter button for 70 seconds and was able to get into some kind of black terminal screen.  But I am so inexperienced that I don't know what it was exactly and I don't know if this is the vulnerability outlined in the article.

As the article suggested, I tried to add this command to the boot configuration, but it didn't work:

```
sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="panic=5 /' /etc/default/grub grub-install
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with full disk encryption.  I've looked around in this forum for a solution but didn't find anything specific to the apparently problem of accessing a LUKS encrypted partition.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: By looking into article, patch needs to be enabled, not only grub. If you are not using LUKS, you shouldn't be afraid.

Comment: That article is scarmongering. The attacker gets access only to the unencrypted `/boot` partition, which does not contain any confidential information; they _do not_ get access to the encrypted data. They can get access to that partition anyway by booting a live session from any bootable medium.

Answer (score 1):

As AlexP said, this article is B.S.  There are a myriad of ways that you can get a root shell ( this one is a bug, but most are intentional ) but without the password you can not access the encrypted data.  Given physical access to the machine there is nothing that can stop you from getting a root shell.  That is the whole reason for using encryption.